# Search doesn't seem to work on Area51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, search

I type in "how to" and hit enter. Nothing happens.
I click on the magnifying glass icon to the left of the box. Nothing happens.

I'm logged in, running Firefox 3.6.3 on Windows 7 with Java/Script and Flash enabled.

Tried from both area51.stackexchange.com and area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=search

resolved: whatever blip caused this is unknown; search now works.

Comment: I'm having this problem again right now. Tried it in chrome, and the restarted chrome, and then in firefox, it just won't 'go'.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably since the words "how" and "to" are [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) which aren't indexed by the database since they are so common.

When I type in "how to", I notice that there are 7 pages on the bottom, which seems like it is showing all the proposals in the database. The only difference is the sort order changes a bit.

For your information, the search happens a second or two after you are done typing. You should see the magnifying glass turn into a spinner for a brief amount of time. It will then show the list of all the proposals in the exact same list you viewed before (i.e. it doesn't take you to a new page). You can also press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to refresh the search. The search only requires JavaScript, not Flash.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have actually tried other words, such as 'electronics', and 'something novel' just to see if this exact problem was the source of my woes. No difference!

Also, I included information on my Java and Flash settings in the bizarre case that they could be interfering with the javascript.

And that seems like an odd break from expected behaviour for a search - users are trained to hit enter at the end of this sort of input. I suppose it would be better in an ideal world - neat, and thanks for the info.

Still not certain why it won't work for me, though.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to try again a moment ago, and search has decided to work. Nothing has changed on my end, and 'how to' with no quotes returns the bottom of the list for me as well at this point.

Very strange, upsetting, but somehow resolved. Thanks again to eagle for the swift (but not used) advice.